# How can i call Auth Authentication using Restfull

Tags: java, rest, oauth

How can i call Auth Authentication using Restfull

i want to send :

```
 Authorization: OAuth realm="Photos",
        oauth_consumer_key="dpf43f3p2l4k3l03",
        oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1",
        oauth_timestamp="137131200",
        oauth_nonce="wIjqoS",
        oauth_callback="http%3A%2F%2Fprinter.example.com%2Fready",
        oauth_signature="74KNZJeDHnMBp0EMJ9ZHt%2FXKycU%3D"
```

I dont khonw more about Auth. so please help.

Comment: Are you using HttpClient for communicating with server ?

Comment: yes i am using HttpClient..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using HTTP client, it becomes very easy to send this header as a part of request. This can be accomplished as follows:

```
HttpGet request = new HttpGet("http://yoursite");
String authStr = "";// Your string starting from OAuth realm="Photos",oauth_consumer_key="dpf43f3p2l4k3l03" ....
request.setHeader("Authorization", authStr );
```

Once you execute this request, a `Authorization` header is sent to the server.